# Updating Documents using MongoDB NodeJS Driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update document using mongodb nodejs driver, I'm not using mongoose just plain mongodb nodejs driver. But I'm getting undefined as the result of updated document. Not able to figure out whats wrong.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/cmecore';
var url2= 'mongodb://localhost:27017/cmeprovisioning';


var findAndUpdateDocuments = function(db) {

  MongoClient.connect(url2, function(err, db2) {

    console.log("Connected to cmeprovisioning");
    var updated=0;

    var cursor =db.collection('physicianTasks').find({"study":"cod","phase":"mansa2","taskStatus":"Complete"});
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {

       var physicianTaskDocument=doc;
       if (doc != null) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.result));

            var assign=doc.assignedTo.toString();
            var phasePhysician=null;

            db2.collection('phasePhysician').findOne
            ({"study":"cod","phase":"mansa2","physicianId":assign},function(err,doc){
              phasePhysician=doc;
              console.log("ID "+phasePhysician._id);
              db2.collection('rhimeReport').updateOne(
                    {"study":"cod","phase":"mansa2","recordStudy":"codstudy",
                    "recordPhase":"mansa2","rhimeTaskId":physicianTaskDocument.rhimeTask.toString(),
                    "recordId":physicianTaskDocument.record.toString(),
                    "tasks.physician":new ObjectID(phasePhysician._id.toString())
                    },
                   {
                     $set: { "tasks.result": physicianTaskDocument.result }
                   },
                   function(err, r) {
                      updated=updated+1;
                      console.log("After Update "+updated +" "+r );
                    }
                  );
            });
       }
  });


  });

}

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected to cmecore");
  findAndUpdateDocuments(db);
});
```

What I'm missing ?

Comment: how about the real data? updated? and last two console.log in findDocuments wont work as you expected because of async nature

Comment: Real data is not updated, can you tell me what changes I should make

Comment: its mean, your query on updateOne is not matching any document. mongoose does automatic data conversion between string, number, boolean, but native driver won't do anything on it.

Comment: Can you also share your db structure?

Comment: forEach  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

Answer (score 0):

In your update statement you have written

```
"tasks.physician":doc._id
```

Try changing it to :

```
"tasks.physician": mongodb.ObjectID.createFromHexString(doc._id);
```

or

```
"tasks.physician": mongodb.ObjectID(doc._id)
```

Comment: I changed and  used ObjectID and it does match documents, but update is not working. I am quite sure its related to async calls

Comment: I have updated the code and removed unnecessary async calls. But in updated document I'm still getting as undefined. Matching criteria in update is correct, I tested by using a find before update. Any clue whats wrong.

Comment: whar is record id & task id ? are they object id ? if yes then change them too